# How to forward scopes to a federated identity provider?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have a WSO2 Identity Server which authenticates my users against an external provider (using the authorization code flow). To trigger the federation, I had to choose against "code" and "implicit" flows for my end users, because these are the only ones that trigger the federation.

Then I chose the "implicit" flow, the problem is that the scopes an user requires are not forwarded to the external identity provider, the only one that's requested is "openid".

How to forward scopes to a federated identity provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put "Additional Query Parameters" as "scope=${scope}" to forward scopes to federated Identity Provider as per request.